# Events not passed to toolbar button when there is a popup over it - Firefox add-on

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, xul

I am having a toolbar button inside a box. And a panel as well inside the same box.

```
<box>
   <panel />
   <toolbarbutton />
</box>
```

When mouseover event is triggered for the toolbarbutton, I am showing the panel using `openPopup` method below the toolbar button.

The problem is when the panel is visible and try to click on the toolbar button, the panel is closed. But, the event is not getting propagated further. I need to click the toolbarbutton.

I tried adding `allowevents="true"` to the panel element. It is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are opening it on `mouseover` event then it is probably a tooltip rather than a real panel - and you want tooltip behavior for it. So it makes sense to actually use the [`<tooltip>` widget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/tooltip) instead of `<panel>` (didn't test but I think that it should give you the behavior you are looking for). The API is pretty much the same for both.

Comment: I tried this. But I am facing a problem. When I use panel, it appears right under my toolbar button, But when I use tooltip, some space is there between the button and popup. I think it appears below the cursor and it is the expected behaviour. Can I change this to appear right below the button?

Comment: @SelvarajMA: Tooltips have some margins set in the default CSS. Set `margin: 0px;` for your tooltip and all will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Use `noautohide`. Set it to `true`.
Here is the [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/Attribute/panel.noautohide)